# can we use opencart or zen cart on the phonegap for an ipad app

Tags: php, iphone, cordova, opencart, zen-cart

Can we use opencart or zencart on the phonegap for an ipad app? 
I want to do a native ipad app using the phonegap framework, can we use php in phonegap? How can i implement open cart template in phonegap,can any one give me some useful tutorial links.

Comment: What app your planning? opencart and zencart is very big application to port in phonegap.

Comment: @PHP Connect some thing like flipcart (except online payment and online booking) and it should not be web app (browser based) it should be a native app

Comment: Basically you want only store product to display but not selling. Then you can do this using xml feeds. That can be easily done using Andoid no need to use phonegap.

Comment: @PHP Connect thanx for ur reply,,actualy i need to use that for an ipad app not for android,,,can u give me some usefull tutorial links regarding that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ravi,

Use of any large framework for small purpose is not a good idea,

As far as your requirement is concern, you can fulfill your need by simple XML feed generation

**Step 1 :**

Understand Database structure of any Open source. i.e. in Zen Cart you can get all category information from zen_categories and zen_categories_description table.

**Step 2 :**

Generate XML feed from DB i.e. create a script which is dynamically generate XML Feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>

<item>
<id>1</id>
<name>Cat 1</name>
<image>http://domain.com/images/cat1.jpg</image>
<description>description goes here</description>
</item>

<item>
<id>2</id>
<name>Cat 2</name>
<image>http://domain.com/images/cat2.jpg</image>
<description>description goes here</description>
</item>

</list>
```

**Step 3 :**

Read XML feed from your native app and display category list.

Now for product data create another XML feed which is use parameter ( category ID)

Hope, this may help.