# Opencart and phonegap

Tags: php, cordova, opencart

Hi I have recently began to build mobile open cart sites for mobile browsers. I would like to take it a step further and build native apps using phonegap. My question is , does phonegap support a structure like opencart? Are php files supported?

Would it be possible for me to build a fully functioning opencart site and integrate it successfully with phonegap?

There is very little information online regarding this question.

Comment: Have a look here: [can we use opencart or zen cart on the phonegap for an ipad app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158493/can-we-use-opencart-or-zen-cart-on-the-phonegap-for-an-ipad-app)

Comment: The issue here is that OpenCart is PHP and MySQL driven. You can call Phonegap to load it via a GET request and load the responsive site that way like an iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Phonegap app cannot contain any server side scripting like PHP. It can only contains HTML, css and Javascript.

But you can always do request to a remote server that runs PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Opencart has quite a few ajax interfaces in various parts of the app. These call controllers that deliver sections of a page usually. I have not looked into the full remote API to know if you can build a full shop app that uses the opencart backend.

If you look down that ajax calls path you may find enough functionality to produce the phonegap app.